# C multithreading: What is the advantage of a Read Lock (pthread_rwlock_rdlock) if all threads can access it simultaneously?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization

I'm noob on this thread issue :\

I imagine that Write Lock behaves like a `while` that waits for the confirmation of a global variable. Like:

```
/* pthread_rwlock_wrlock */

    while (is_blocked) {
        /* waiting */
    }
    is_blocked = true;

    (writing code...)

/* pthread_rwlock_unlock */
    is_blocked = false;
```

Is that correct? And how Read Lock works? If it is shared, why use?

**information:**

pthread_rwlock_rdlock() – get a shared read lock

pthread_rwlock_wrlock() – get an exclusive write lock

Comment: Conceptually it may be similar. But in effect it won't be a busy wait loop, simply because that's a huge waste of CPU cycles that can be doing something useful. The waiting threads will not be scheduled for execution at all until the lock is released, and then one of them will be chosen by some strategy.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of a read lock, is to block writers.

- A **reader** can get a lock if there are **no write locks**.
- A **writer** can get a lock if there are **no locks at all**.

Neither has a trivial implementation, the one
you suggested for 
 example have a race-condition, 
and would sometimes fail.

Answer (score 2):

When you read a protected resource you don't want it to change while you read it.

A read locks blocks write locks!

That means that while you have a read lock, someone trying to get a write lock will have to wait until you, and anyone else who has a read lock, are finished reading. Since reading doesn't change the resource it is OK that several readers read concurrently.

Note that the definition of a reading operation in this context is any operation that doesn't change the state of the protected resource. So for the purposes of read/write locks, if the protected resource is a stream (like `stdin` or a socket), reading from it will change its state and should require a write lock.